# R: How to display the number of points in each scatterplot category?

Tags: r, plotly

If I have a Plot.ly plot such as this scatterplot:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library("plotly"))
plot_ly(data = iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, mode = "markers",
        color = Species)
```

[image: plotly sample scatterplot]

How can I have the number of points per category displayed? For example, I would want the legend to look something like this:

- virginica - 35
- versicolor - 44
- setosa - 28

Where the numbers are the total number of points shown. Is there a way to do this with Plot.ly such that the value shown will reflect the number of points that are displayed on the plot? Are there other ways to implement this using Plot.ly?

Answer (score 2):

```
n <- count(iris, Species) %>% mutate(new = paste(Species, '-', n))
levels(iris$Species) <- n$new

plotly::plot_ly(data = iris, x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, mode = "markers",
        color = Species)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is hard-coding the number of entries in the legend. I guess I wasn't clear but I am interested in a Plot.ly-centric solution, especially one that will update as a sub-selection of the data points are shown on the plot.